# condition in recursion - best practise

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, conditional-statements

what's the best practise to break a loop?
my ideas were:

```
Child Find(Parent parent, object criteria)
{
    Child child = null;

    foreach(Child wannabe in parent.Childs)
    {
        if (wannabe.Match(criteria))
        {
            child = wannabe;
        }
        else
        {
            child = Find(wannabe, criteria);
        }

        if (child != null) break;
    }

    return child;
}
```

or

```
Child Find(Parent parent, object criteria)
{
    Child child = null;
    var conditionator = from c in parent.Childs where child != null select c;

    foreach(Child wannabe in conditionator)
    {
        if (wannabe.Match(criteria))
        {
            child = wannabe;
        }
        else
        {
            child = Find(wannabe, criteria);
        }
    }

    return child;
}
```

or

```
Child Find(Parent parent, object criteria)
{
    Child child = null;
    var enumerator = parent.Childs.GetEnumerator();

    while(child != null && enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (enumerator.Current.Match(criteria))
        {
            child = wannabe;
        }
        else
        {
            child = Find(wannabe, criteria);
        }
    }

    return child;
}
```

what do u think, any better ideas?
i'm looking for the niciest solution :D

mo

Comment: Which version of .NET/C# does this need to work in?

Comment: You're calling Find recursively in all examples so does that mean Child inherits from Parent?

Comment: its just pseudo code :) lets imagine an interface IFinder :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linq may be more terse, but can be more difficult to understand!

```
    Child Find(Parent parent, object criteria)
    {
        return parent.Childs.Select(        // Loop through the children looking for those that match the following criteria
            c => c.Match(criteria)          // Does this child match the criteria?
                ? c                         // If so, just return this child
                : this.Find(c, criteria)    // If not, try to find it in this child's children
        ).FirstOrDefault();                 // We're only interested in the first child that matches the criteria or null if none found
    }
```

Comment: @mo LOL! You don't like the multiple return statements on the claim that it's hard to debug, but this is acceptable? Try stepping through with a debugger and see which you'll prefer a few months from now when the code isn't fresh in your mind. :-)

Comment: this is really a cool solution.but some devs in my team will never understand it :) for them it is hard to understand.

Comment: it has one return :). the debugging issue still exist

Comment: it is hard to understand (for unexp. devs).
but for a simple recursive search it will do the job.
(it is not debuggable) :)

Comment: Does this actually terminate after the first positive hit?

Comment: @John yes, the `FirstOrDefault` will ensure no more than one positive result will be extracted. It won't even evaluate `c.Match` or `this.Find` on any items after the first positive match due to Linq's lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for you to deal with the `IEnumerator` yourself, so option 3 is out.

Option 2 does not function. It continues regardless of finding a match, and if the last child is not a match and its children do not contain a match, then the result will be `null` even if there was a prior match.

Option 1 seems the cleanest, assuming you object to multiple `return` statements.

Comment: @mo: The issue is still there with option 2.

Comment: Option 1 has a problem that it will continue to recursively search for a match in the other children even when it has already found one.

Comment: @Ants: No, it won't; option 2 will do that, not option 1.

Comment: i didnt see my fault @ 2.the linq-expr. breaks if child != null.
so the foreach will break.

i'm blind!

Comment: Somebody did an edit after I posted. That "if (child != null) break;" line was not there originally in option 1. The "break" used to be in the success clause.

Comment: I agree with Adam about 1 being the cleanest (I would have been stronger and said only IF you use return statements). As an aside,I do not get why people down vote here without any explanation, and SO should automatically down vote anonymous down voters who ddon't explain themselves, IMO. Cheers